# Find all complex numbers z such that $(z+1)^4 = (z+i)^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following problem:

> Find all complex numbers z such that $(z+1)^4 = (z+i)^2$

I'm stuck after trying to see it as a difference of squares:

$((z+1)^2)^2-(z+i)^2=0$

$((z+1)^2 + (z+i)) ((z+1)^2-(z+i))=0$

I've tried expanding it and comparing it to a binomial form (such as $a+bi$). But I end up with something that doesn't seem right and I still can't come to an answer.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You reduced the problem to solving two quadratics in $z$. So just do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z^2+2z+1-z-i=z^2+z+1-i=0$$
$$z=\{-1-i,i\}$$
and for the other factor:
$$z^2+2z+1+z+i=z^2+3z+1+i=0$$
$$z=\left\{-\frac32\pm\sqrt{5-4i}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\left(\frac{(z+1)^2}{z+i}\right)^2=1=e^{2\pi i n}$$

for $n\in\mathbb Z$. So then,

$$\frac{(z+1)^2}{z+i}=e^{\pi i n}=(-1)^n$$

Now we just need to solve this quadratic properly.